# how to set image to imageview center with background color on swift

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an image as 30x30. I want to put this image into center of another 500x500 image and i want to define a background for 500x500 image like the following example. Is there any way to achieve this? Thank you.

[image: İmages]

Comment: Use AutoLayout and add the 500*500 image first and then add the 30*30 UIImage on top of it with a fixed height and width.

Comment: Btw if you could show what you have done so far, people here would be able to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Set the image as following, just keep in mind that image's background color should be clear.

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "search_image")
imageView.contentMode = .center
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with the help of storyboard as shown in below picture.[image]

and output is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set width/height fix for the image. Insert into the background view with constraints centerX and centerY.